# how do i ask a question about "fix Lighthouse returned error"?

Tags: lighthouse

i tested my site, and got the error code form yesterday night.
but yesterday afternoon was working fine.

Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: Extension result empty. Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with https://www.wowlavie.com/ Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit() before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5555:13) at http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:708:9 at Map.forEach () at chromium.DevTools.Connection.dispatchMessage (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:707:76) at chromium.DevTools.Connection.onJsonMessage_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:689:65) at :1:40

could you help me to solve the problem?
thank you a lot!

Comment: Possibly related: [error on scanning](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/10164).